conda: command not found after moving from one directory to another
I followed this [guidline](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/working-with-conda/configurations/move-directory/#moving-from-one-directory-to-another)
I don't know why after reboot I can't run any command conda.
OS: Linux (20.04)



~/.bashrc

How can I fix that?
I have spent hours on researching on internet, but I can't find anything.
I'm sorry for taking some pictures like this because actually I have no other way to describe my situation. Thanks a lot!
